# How to install WebkitGTK in MacOS?

Tags: macos, webkit, webkitgtk

```
brew install webkitgtk
```

Not finding package, when installing from macports it doesn't finding by gtk-rs when compiling my project on rust with gtk-rs and webkit2gtk-rs

Answer (score 1):

based on the mailing list, webkit2gtk has some blockers for working on macOS and requires a lot of patching. To which is easier said than done because there are no patches yet that I'm aware of

Answer (score 0):

WebKitGTK+ is now available on the main MacPorts ports source.

Comment: couldn't find this port on macports, yes trying to build Nyxt...